# Unity3d Sprite change with prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine, themes, 2d, sprite, switching

Ive a question about how to change spirte images during runtime for a bunch of objects.

So i made a tiny racer 2d game, and therefore you can choose differend themes. You have this option in an integraded menu (not a seperate scene).

My question:
Can i switch the sprites easy during the runtime? Ive made prefabs for each track element - and i changed the sprites of those prefabs, but the change only gets visible, after the scene is reloaded. So i would need to avoid this.

Has someone a solution or a hint how i could do that?

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
public class Background_Controller : MonoBehaviour {
public Camera mainCamera;
public Color colorNormal; 

public GameObject[] Prefabs;

public Sprite[] normalSprites;
public Sprite[] tronSprites;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {

    SwitchBackgroundFunction(); 

}


public void SwitchBackground(string Theme)
{

    switch(Theme)
    {

        case "GreenHell":
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Theme", "Normal");

            break;

        case "NeonCity":
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Theme", "Tron");

            break;

    }

    SwitchBackgroundFunction(); 

}

private void SwitchBackgroundFunction()
{
    int prefabCount = Prefabs.Length;

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("Theme") == "Normal")
    {
        mainCamera.backgroundColor = colorNormal;

        for (int i = 0; i <= prefabCount - 1; i++)
        {
            Prefabs[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = normalSprites[i];
        }
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("Theme") == "Tron")
    {
        mainCamera.backgroundColor = Color.black;

        for (int i = 0; i <= prefabCount - 1; i++)
        {
            Prefabs[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = tronSprites[i];
        }
    }

}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, you need to post your code so that people won't post something that you have tried. Edit your question, add the language tag then the code you are using to change the Sprite.

Comment: I simply filled the prefab objects into the GameObject Prefabs Array, also the differend sprites of my Themes sprite sheet into normalSprites / tronSprites Array. And because i have so many placed objects in my scene (tiles with a bunch of assets which would have to be changed) i thougt i would change the sprites of the prefabs, the objects are depending on to change all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the following lines to swap in a sprite from within your resources folder during runtime.

```
Sprite spr;
spr = Resources.Load<Sprite>("mysprite"); //insert name and file path to sprite within Resources folder
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spr;
```